# Where to find the pages to modify content on magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages

We have Magento 1.9 for our site. I am taking over, and I would like to make some changes on the pages of our site. It is my first time working with Magento, what I would like to know is where to find the page templates to go in my text editor and make changes accordingly.

For example I am trying to start making changes to the url below.

https://www.jauniforms.com/customer/account/login/

Thanks!

Comment: Generally those files are found in `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/`. You should consider looking at how to enable template path hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily any pages or files find using Template path hints 
[How to enable template path hints](https://nwdthemes.com/2016/07/14/magento-1-x-enable-template-path-hints/)